# Python: given a plane equation draw a subset of points that belong to it

Tags: python, matplotlib, linear-algebra, mplot3d

As the title say, let's assume I have a plane equation:

> ax+by+cz=d    (e.g. -4x + 5y + 9z = -9)

I want to draw n random points (let's say 500) that belong to that plane.
Can somebody help me with that?

I saw that `from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d` has the function `plot_surface(x,y,z)` but (as it says) it plots the surface equation and this is not what I need.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: just get random values for x and y and use them to calculate z using your equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a plane a simple approach that would work is

1. pick a coefficient that's not 0 (let's suppose is `c`)
2. pick random values for the other two coordinates (`x` and `y` in this case)
3. compute `z` with `(d - ax - by)/c`

Comment: What happens if my "c" is instead c=0?

Comment: @NiccolòCacciotti: then choose another (e.g. `b`; pick random `x` and `z` and then compute `y`)